# ksql - Aggregating data based on last 1 year ( 365 days)

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I would like to build sql query to have aggregation done for last 1 year. In this case, window size is last 365 days. Is it possible to do it using ksql ?  Like the following query

```
  SELECT regionid, regioncity, COUNT(*) FROM pageviews
  WINDOW HOPPING (SIZE 30 SECONDS, ADVANCE BY 10 SECONDS)
  GROUP BY regionid, regioncity ;
```

My question is :  When we specify 'SIZE 30 seconds' or 'SIZE 3600 seconds', will it start the window from start of the stream or from latest ?

Comment: Did you set auto offset reset anywhere? That's the only property that determines where to start, not the size of the window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The start date and time of windows is based on the Unix epoch. It has no bearing on the timestamp of the messages on the source topic.

Windows greater than a day will start at the Unix epoch and increment from there. Because there's no `YEAR` size and you're using 365 days you'll find that the window starts on 20th December (because of leap years)

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(WINDOWSTART(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss','Europe/London') AS WINDOW_START_TS, 
             CUSTOMER, 
             SUM(COST) 
        FROM SOURCE_DATA 
                WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 365 DAYS) 
        GROUP BY CUSTOMER 
        EMIT CHANGES ;    

+-----------------------+----------+------------+
|WINDOW_START_TS        |CUSTOMER  |KSQL_COL_2  |
+-----------------------+----------+------------+
|2018-12-20 00:00:00    |A         |4           |
|2019-12-20 00:00:00    |A         |2           |
```

I've written this up here: 
https://rmoff.net/2020/01/09/exploring-ksqldb-window-start-time/